# about std::result_of in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

As I know, a possible implementation of `std::result_of` is

```
template<class F, class... ArgTypes>
struct result_of<F(ArgTypes...)>
{
    typedef decltype(
        std::declval<F>()(std::declval<ArgTypes>()...)
        ) type;
};
```

But when I use `std::result_of` I have some trouble.

```
int f(int x)
{
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>    
void Test(const T& t)
{
    decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<int>())) i1 = 1; // ok
    typename std::result_of<T(int)>::type i2 = 2; // compile error:
    // function returning a function
    // I think this means the same thing just as above, right?
}

int main()
{
    Test(f);
    return 0;
}
```

What are the differences between these two forms?

Comment: Well, `T(int)` is simply not a valid type in C++ when `T = int(int)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I suggest making that an answer. It's the most logical thing I can think of.

Comment: @MarcoA.: Done. I was lazy and didn't want to look up the details, though I now also figured out what the OP should have wanted to say.

Comment: FYI, that is *not* a valid implementation of `std::result_of`: it's required to do the same dance with pointer-to-members as `std:bind` et al.

Answer (score 5):

`std::result_of` is declared in C++11 [meta.trans.other] Table 57 as:

```
template <class Fn, class... ArgTypes> struct result_of<Fn(ArgTypes...)>;
```

and it requires that:

> `Fn` shall be a callable type (20.8.1), reference to function, or reference to callable type. The expression
>
> ```
> decltype(INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...))
> ```
>
> shall be well formed.

*callable type* is defined in [func.def]/3:

> A *callable type* is a function object type (20.8) or a pointer to member.

*function object type* is defined in [function.objects]/1:

> A *function object type* is an object type (3.9) that can be the type of the *postfix-expression* in a function call (5.2.2, 13.3.1.1). ...

In your program, `f` is a reference to a function of type `int(int)`, so `T` is deduced to the function type `int(int)`. Note that a function type is *not* one of the valid options for the type `Fn` to be passed to `std::result_type`. A reference to function *is* an acceptable type, however: you should pass the full type of `Test`s parameter to `result_of` instead of only `T` ([Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d9621a00c6abf6c)):

```
template<typename T>    
void Test(const T&)
{
    decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<int>())) i1 = 1;
    typename std::result_of<const T& (int)>::type i2 = 2;
}
```

Regarding the difference between the two forms, remember that `std::declval` always returns a reference type; specifically `std::declval<T>()` returns `T&&`. So

```
decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<int>()))
```

is asking for the what type is returned when a `T&&` is invoked with an `int&&` argument.

Comment: Thank you.I understand now.But about"A callable type is a function object type (20.8) or a pointer to member."Does a pointer to member mean either a pointer to member function or a pointer to global function?

Comment: @LeonhartSquall No - pointer-to-member-function types are very much distinct from pointer-to-function types. Pointer-to-function types *do* work with `std::result_of` nonetheless, because a pointer-to-function is a *function object type* and therefore a *callable type*.

Comment: @Casey.Did you mean a pointer-to-function is a function object or a function object type?

Answer (score 4):

[basic.compound] describes what function types look like in C++:

> — *functions*, which have parameters of given types and return `void` or references or objects of a given type

Therefore, the return type part of a function type must not itself be a function type, and thus `T(int)` is not a valid type in the C++ type system when `T = int(int)`.

Moreover, [dcl.fct]/8 clarifies:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function

Note also that the actual analogue of your `i1` line is `typename std::result_of<T>::type i2`.

Comment: `std::result_of<T>::type` (i.e., `std::result_of<int(int)>` in the OP) [is ill-formed since `int` is not a "callable type, reference to function, or reference to callable type"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14bfc654c8d92b05).