# Is a pointer-to-function is a function object type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In my opinion,function object is a class that implements `operator()`.

```
class Functor
{
public:
    int operator()(int a, int b)
    {
     ...
    }
};
```

But,in the other question I asked([about std::result_of in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867294/about-stdresult-of-in-c11)),Casey point that a pointer-to-function is a function object type and therefore a callable type.

And in c++ reference:

> A function object type is an object type (3.9) that can be the type of the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2, 13.3.1.1)
>
> An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type.(3.9)

So it seems that a pointer-to-function is can be treated as a function object,though it turned my opinion of function object.Is that right?

Comment: No, pointer to function is not a function object type. Both are callable types though. Can you point out the line where Casey says that function pointer is a function object type - I couldn't find it.

Comment: in the comment you can find that: "@LeonhartSquall No - pointer-to-member-function types are very much distinct from pointer-to-function types. Pointer-to-function types do work with std::result_of nonetheless, because a pointer-to-function is a function object type and therefore a callable type. –  Case"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A function object type is an object type (3.9) that can be the type of the postfix-expression in a function call.
>
> §20.8 [function.objects]

Footnote 230 (N3337), attached to the above sentence in the standard, states:

> Such a type is **a function pointer** or a class type which has a member operator() or a class type which has a conversion to a pointer to function.

Therefore, a function pointer type is a function object type.  The standard goes on:

> A function object is an object of a function object type.
>
> §20.8 [function.objects]

Therefore a function pointer, being of function object type, is a function object.

Note that, in spite of the traditional connotations of "object", pointers are objects in C++:

> An object is a region of storage.
>
> §1.8 [intro.object]

Pointers, occuying a region of storage, are therefore objects.

Answer (score 2):

Every pointer type is an object type. This follows from the definition of "object type" quoted in the question details. In particular, function pointer types are object types.

A function pointer type can be the type of the *postfix-expression* in a function call. For example, if `p` has type `void (*)()`, then the expression `p()` calls the function pointed to by `p`. So a function pointer type indeed meets the requirements of a function object type.